# Set dynamically created TextView on frame layout

Tags: android

I want to pass some data from one activity to another and set it in dynamically created `TextView` over frame layout of that activity..I'm using intent for that but at second activity the data is not getting extracted..Can any one tell me the simple way for this..
Following is my code..

Hidden.java

```
public class Hidden extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
Button btnnameadd, btnnameremove, btnmobileadd, btnmobileremove, btndone;
EditText etname, etmobile;
ImageView ivlogo;
private AlertDialog dialog;
private Uri mImageCaptureUri;
Intent jump;
//options for image selection
private static final int PICK_FROM_CAMERA = 1;
private static final int CROP_FROM_CAMERA = 2;
private static final int PICK_FROM_FILE = 3;
LinearLayout llname, llmobile, llimage;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.hidden);
        captureImageInitialization();

        init();

}

private void init() {
    etname=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextname);
    etmobile=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextmobile);
    btnnameadd=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonnameadd);
    btnnameremove=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonnameremove);
    btnmobileadd=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonmobileadd);
    btnmobileremove=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonmobileremove);
    btndone=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttondone);
    llname=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.name);
    llmobile=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mobile);
    btnnameadd.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnnameadd.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnnameremove.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnmobileadd.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnmobileremove.setOnClickListener(this);
    btndone.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    jump=new Intent(Hidden.this,Framelayout.class);
    if(v.getId()==R.id.buttonnameadd)
    {
        String strname=etname.getText().toString();
        Log.d("Log",strname);
        jump.putExtra("Name",strname);
    }else if(v.getId()==R.id.buttonnameremove)
    {
        btnnameremove.setEnabled(false);
        llname.removeView(findViewById(R.id.editTextname));
    }else if(v.getId()==R.id.buttonmobileadd)
    {
        String strmobile=etmobile.getText().toString();
        Log.d("Log",strmobile);
        jump.putExtra("Mobile",strmobile);
        Log.d("LOG",jump.putExtra("Mobile",strmobile).toString());
    }else if(v.getId()==R.id.buttonmobileremove)
    {
        llmobile.removeView(findViewById(R.id.editTextmobile));         
    }else if(v.getId()==R.id.buttondone)
    {
        Log.d("LOG","1");
        startActivity(jump);
    }
}
```

}

FrameLayout.java

```
public class Framelayout extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
FrameLayout frameLayout;
Button b2,b3;
//private ProgressDialog pDialog;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_framelayout);
    frameLayout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.f1);
     b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
     b3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonload);
 b2.setOnClickListener(this);
     b3.setOnClickListener(this);

  }
public void onClick(View v) {
     if(v.getId()==R.id.button2){
        Intent i=new Intent(Framelayout.this,Hidden.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }else if(v.getId()==R.id.buttonload){
        Log.d("Log",getIntent().getStringExtra("Name"));
         editframelayout();
    }
}

private void editframelayout() {
    String name=getIntent().getExtras().getString("Name");
    String mobile=getIntent().getExtras().getString("Mobile");
    TextView tvname=new TextView(this);
    tvname.setText(name);
    tvname.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    tvname.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    TextView tvmobile=new TextView(this);
    tvmobile.setText(mobile);
    tvmobile.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    tvmobile.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    frameLayout.addView(tvname);
    frameLayout.addView(tvmobile);
}
```

}

Comment: Post your code what you've tried till now.

Comment: Can you put your activity code here?

Comment: +1 to say *Welcome to SO* (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use one of `putExtra()` overloaded methods of the `intent` instance you created to add your data.

Here is a sample:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SignoutActivity.class); // # this parameter is the context of the caller
intent.putExtra("PARAM_TEXTBOX_TEXT", textboxText);
startActivity(intent);
```

Edit for the code you added, your design is very poor and doesn't accomplish what is intended.

Every time you click a `Button` a **new instance** of `Intent` is created. you are calling `startActivity()` only in single case:

```
else if(v.getId()==R.id.buttondone)
{
    Log.d("LOG","1");
    startActivity(jump);
}
```

Now you assume that the *parameters added in previous button clicks are still there*, but they aren't. When you click `buttondone` you create a new instance of `Intent` with no extras at all.

You can work this around as follows:

```
...
else if(v.getId()==R.id.buttondone)
{
    String strname = etname.getText().toString();
    if (strname != null && !strname.equals(""))
    {
        jump.putExtra("Name",strname);                
    }

    String strmobile = etmobile.getText().toString();
    if (strmobile != null && !strmobile.equals(""))
    {
        jump.putExtra("Mobile",strmobile);            
    }

    startActivity(jump);
}
```

It still isn't well structured, but might do the trick for you

Comment: Thanks you so much,,,you ware right..I put all my data on done button click and it passed,,,,

Answer (score 0):

Use **getIntent().getStringExtra("Name")** instead of **getIntent().getExtras().getString("Name");**

```
getIntent().getStringExtra("Name")
```